# How can I guarantee that an interface and a class method parameters match without manually checking?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I recently noticed a bug due to a mismatched parameter order in the class to its interface parameter order.  I felt that this should have been a compile error.  I found out that Interfaces do not constrain the parameter names.  So if you see my example below I have `firstParameter` and `secondParameter` reversed, I also have `parameterOne` and `parameterTwo`, both as valid builds.  This may build just fine, but you will likely run into runtime errors.

On the other hand, it does require the order of the types of the parameters to match.  So I thought perhaps I do not need to place the parameter names in the interface and just the value types, but that does not work and the interface would still need to provide a description of what the types are in terms of what a consumer would place there.

**My Question**
Is there a way to guarantee at build time that a class matches the interface parameter names?  I would prefer not to do this manually.

The reason this is important is even though the method variables cannot be setup to be used by the interface, someone consuming a service reference or other use of an interface would see the Interface parameters at the time of setup and that is the expected use of the parameters.  If I cannot rely on a contract to be exact, what is the point of a contract in the first place?

```
interface IParameterTest
{
    void TwoStringParameters(string firstParameter, string secondParameter);

    void TwoStringParametersAndAnInt(string firstParameter, string secondParameter, int thirdParameter);
}

public class ParameterTest : IParameterTest
{
    //Builds and matches interface
    //public void TwoStringParameters(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
    //{
    //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    //Builds and does not match interface
    //public void TwoStringParameters(string secondParameter, string firstParameter)
    //{
    //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    //Builds and does not match interface
    public void TwoStringParameters(string parameterOne, string parameterTwo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //Builds and matches interface
    public void TwoStringParametersAndAnInt(string firstParameter, string secondParameter, int thirdParameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //Does not build or match interface
    //public void TwoStringParametersAndAnInt(int firstParameter, string secondParameter, string thirdParameter)
    //{
    //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}
}
```

Comment: Parameter names are not part of the method signature, partly because there would be no way for the compiler to know which overload you're calling unless you used explicit parameter names:  `TwoStringParameters(firstParameter = "One", secondParameter = "Two")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to guarantee at build time that a class matches the interface parameter names? I would prefer not to do this manually.

Not within the C# language. However:

- You could write a unit test to check, reasonably easily. Not quite build time, but still early enough to catch errors before they're big problems.
- You could write a Roslyn code diagnostic to flag it as an error (and even provide a code fix for it).

Of course, the unit test could be written via Roslyn as well, but you could do it fairly easily just using plain reflection.

It's not entirely clear from your question whether you've spotted the really nasty problem with parameter names being wrong, by the way - it's not just in terms of human readability, but it can significantly affect behaviour if you use named arguments. For example, suppose you have code like this:

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    void Foo(int x, int y);
}

public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    public void Foo(int y, int x) { ... }
}

...
IFoo foo = new FooImpl();
foo.Foo(x: 10, y: 20); // Equivalent to foo.Foo(10, 20)
```

Now if someone decides to use `var` instead, the compile-time type of `foo` is changed, so suddenly the named arguments map to different parameters.

```
var foo = new FooImpl();
foo.Foo(x: 10, y: 20); // Equivalent to foo.Foo(20, 10)
```

Perfectly valid code... but with a different meaning to the previous code. There are other times that changing the compile-time type of a variable can affect things, but that's *usually* around overloading etc... this is in the simple case where there really is just one method.

Comment: Yes I did.  I was dealing with GIS data and the parameters were xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax.  And I am passing them via AJAX so the order can switch easily on both sides and it was driving me batty.  Thank you for the additional information and the answer, I will mark as accepted once the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon says, C# doesn't really care what the parameters are called, but if you wanted to reflectively assert the parameter names for yourself; either at start up or in a unit test, you could use something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program));

        var types = assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.GetInterfaces().Any());

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.Assembly == assembly);

            foreach (var iface in interfaces)
            {
                var classMethods = type.GetMethods();

                foreach (var interfaceMethod in iface.GetMethods())
                {
                    var classMethod = classMethods.First(x => x.ToString() == interfaceMethod.ToString());

                    Debug.Assert(
                        interfaceMethod.GetParameters().Select(x => x.Name).SequenceEqual(classMethod.GetParameters().Select(x => x.Name)),
                        "Incorrect parameter names in method: " + type.Name + "." + classMethod.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        void MethodA(string first, string second);
    }

    public class TestA : ITest
    {
        public void MethodA(string first, string second) { }
    }

    public class TestB : ITest
    {
        public void MethodA(string second, string first) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a few build-time alternatives. You'd have to weigh whether they are worth the effort.

- create a custom static code analysis rule (what used to be FxCop)
- use Roslyn and plug it into MSBuild
- something completely custom plugged into MSBuild that fails the build if you don't have a match

Your question

> If I cannot rely on a contract to be exact, what is the point of a contract in the first place?

is worth considering, however *names of required parameters* as contractual requirement may be considered quite narrow. There is a compile-time way to fix this, and you've even suggested it in your question: you are bound by the order, number and type of parameters. If you needed a very strict interface, you could abstract the parameters by wrapping the simple types, preventing a case such as accidental argument swapping.

Again, you'd have to weigh whether it's worth it. You're buying interface safety at the cost of more code and cognitive load.

Comment: In this particular case since it is a WCF service the interface is there for the service contract.  I generally like the ideas of interfaces, but I did not know before this issue that the parameters were not constrained.  I will certainly weigh the pros and cons when I am not using WCF services for the use of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

[FxCop already has a rule to enforce this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182251.aspx). You can [enable code analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e05a02t4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to run on build in your project properties, then configure the code analysis rule set to treat that warning as an error. If you integrate that into your build process you will force all your developers to address that issue before their builds will succeed.

Comment: I ran code analysis previous to this issue using Visual Studio 2013 and it did not catch this.  I found this as a result of data not returning properly.  It caught several other nice things, and this would be something that would be nice to show up there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest a much better solution is to refactor the interface to use the parameter object design pattern rather than messing around with enforcing the parameter names of two strings are implemented in the correct order.

Example if string 1 was "firstName" and string 2 was "lastName" you are much better off with a class with two properties FirstName and SecondName and then have your interface depend on this parameter object rather than low level data types such as strings.